# "Error: NEXT_REDIRECT" using "redirect()" in NextJS 14 while trying to redirect user if response is not ok

Tags: redirect, next.js

For your information, I am a new noob to programming.

**Background**:
I am creating authentication for my app. I am using NextJS 14 with AppRouter and laravel on the backend to manage tokens. I have created a function in nextJS where it simply checks whether the user is authenticated or not by simply sending a request using fetchAPI to the laravel endpoint and if the response is not OK (i.e 401 (Unauthorized)) then the user should be redirected to homepage (i.e "/").

**The Error**:
When I try to use NextJS function "redirect()". It throws an error:
`Error: NEXT_REDIRECT`

**My Code**:

```
import { redirect } from "next/navigation";
import { hasCookie } from "cookies-next";
import { cookies } from "next/headers";
import { BASE_URL, API_ENDPOINTS } from "@/app/data/api";

export default function useAuth() {
  const existingToken = hasCookie("token", { cookies }); // returns 'true' if the token exists

  console.log("existing token?", existingToken);
  const cookiesSet = cookies();

  const checkUser = async () => {
    if (existingToken) {
      const token = cookiesSet.get("token").value; // returns the token from cookies
      console.log("the token: ", token);

      try {
        const response = await fetch(
          `${BASE_URL}${API_ENDPOINTS.PROFILE_DETAILS}`,
          {
            headers: {
              Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
              "Content-Type": "application/json",
            },
          }
        );

        if (!response.ok) {
          console.log("User is not authenticated, response not ok");
          redirect("/"); // The issue is here. It does not redirect
        }
      } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error:", error.message);
      }
    }
  };

  checkUser();

  return null; // Return null to avoid rendering any content
}
```

My "dashboard/page.jsx" (where I am calling the function)

```
import useAuth from '../Auth/hooks/useAuth';

export default function Dashboard() {

   useAuth();
  
  return (
    <>
    dashobard
    </>
  )
}
```

**Note**:
I want this redirect functionality on the server side.

**What I am trying to Achieve**:
I want to create a general function for server side redirection. Whenever I call it in any of my page.jsx. It should check if the user is not authorized then it should be redirected to homepage.

**What I tried**
I tried to get things done using "useRouter" but later discovered it only works on client-side. I am wandering for 2 days to get the solution. Even ChatGPT was unable to help me.

Answer (score 2):

`redirect()` throws an error where the message is `NEXT_REDIRECT` as you can see and in the [source code](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/blob/canary/packages/next/src/client/components/redirect.ts#L6C30-L6C43), which later captured by Next.js to do the redirection. So it should not be called in a `try-catch`. They have kinda worn about that on the [doc](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/functions/redirect):

> In Server Actions and Route Handlers, redirect should be called after the `try/catch` block.

If you cannot avoid calling it within the `try-catch`, you may do as follows:

```
catch (error) {
  if (error.message === "NEXT_REDIRECT") throw error;
  // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After banging my head against the wall and ChatGPT for 3 consecutive days, at last, I figured out the solution.

I changed my file name from "useAuth" to "verifyAuth" (just for correction of naming convention. Thanks to Youssuf Oumar)

In the `checkUser()` function, I returned user data which is either the actual data of the user or it is a string "Unauthorized".

Then outside the `checkUser()` function, I created a const and put the `checkUser()` function inside it and also added `await` it so that it waits for the promise to resolve. (To add the `await`, I had to make my `verifyAuth()` function async too.)

After that, In the "page.jsx", I made my `Dashboard()` function async and added `await` to the `verifyAuth()` function.

That worked!

Here is the code of my "verifyAuth.js":

```
// RESPONSIBLE FOR REDIRECTION TO LOGIN PAGE IF TOKEN IS NOT VALID

import { redirect } from "next/navigation";
import { hasCookie } from "cookies-next";
import { cookies } from "next/headers";
import { BASE_URL, API_ENDPOINTS } from "@/app/data/api";

export default async function verifyAuth() {
  const existingToken = hasCookie("token", { cookies }); // returns 'true' 
if the token exists

  console.log("existing token?", existingToken);
  const cookiesSet = cookies();

 const checkUser = async () => {
   if (existingToken) {
      const token = cookiesSet.get("token").value; // returns the token from cookies
      console.log("the token: ", token);

      const response = await fetch(
        `${BASE_URL}${API_ENDPOINTS.PROFILE_DETAILS}`,
        {
          headers: {
            Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
          },
        }
      );
      const data = await response.json();
      return data.user; // either the data of the user or it returns 
'Unauthorized' 
     } else {
      redirect("/");
    }
  };

  const isUser = await checkUser();
  if (isUser === "Unauthorized") {
    redirect("/");
  }
}
```

Here is my "page.jsx":

```
import verifyAuth from "../Auth/verifyAuth";

export default async function Dashboard() {
  await verifyAuth();

  return <>dashobard</>;
}
```